# typing "android" in firefox opens a apache2 Ubuntu Default Page

Tags: firefox, apache2

Whenever I search for the word `android` through firefox' address bar, a page titled `Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page` opens up.
[image]

What is this page all about and what does it have to do with Ubuntu?

BTW I'm running `Ubuntu 14.04` and `Mozilla Firefox 36.0.4`

**EDIT:** Here is the output of  `nmap android`

```
Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-03-27 22:05 IST
Nmap scan report for android (127.0.53.53)
Host is up (0.00041s latency).
Not shown: 997 closed ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
80/tcp  open  http
139/tcp open  netbios-ssn
445/tcp open  microsoft-ds

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1.60 seconds
```

Comment: Is apache installed in your computer? Is your computer named "android"?

Comment: @EricCarvalho Apache looks to be installed on my system(although I have no Idea how/why or when, probably got installed when I installed various network tools like nmap or wireshark). I only have got a single PC, but android is there at `127.0.55.55`. It might be the android phone which I use for thethring, I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the android device used for usb tethering which shows up as a server on the network.

The page is shown because `apache` is installed on the computer, and it thinks that android, located at 127.0.55.55 is a website. As the so called website(the phone) does not have any webpage, apache shows the default page instead.

As Apache is not needed on a desktop, uninstalling it fixes the problem.

To uninstall apache, you can use

```
sudo apt-get remove apache2
```

Answer (score 0):

I concur with Eric Carvalho's comment. I assume you're typing android in the URL bar vs the top-right search box? It seems a PC is named android on your network. You can try ping, nslookup PC-NAME to identify it. You could use a port scanner (nmap or telnet PC-NAME 80) to see if its got apache (a web server) installed on it